# How can I implement the logic of a game in the GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create the game Connect Four and I created the GUI using swing where every "box" is a button with an image that represents the color of the player. I wrote the logic of the game in an another class but now if I write this main it won't even show me the buttons,while if I only create a new GUI it does

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connect4 grid = new Connect4();
    grid.inizializeGrid(7,6);
    Connect4GUI GUI= new Connect4GUI();
}
```

EDIT: these are the two classe,they are in Italian sorry Forza4 = Connect4

```
package Forza4;

import java.util.Random;

public class Forza4 {

public boolean aggiungiPedina(int[][]g,int col,int p){
    boolean spazio = false;
    int indiceRiga = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<g.length;i++){
        if( g[i][col]==0 ){
            spazio = true;
            indiceRiga=i;
        }
    }
    if( !spazio ){
        return false;
    }
    g[indiceRiga][col]=p;
    return true;
}

public int[][] inizializzaGriglia(int n,int m,int t){
    int[][] griglia = new int[n][m];
    Random r = new Random();
    int primoGiocatore = r.nextInt(2)+1;
    int secondoGiocatore = primoGiocatore==1 ? 2: 1;
    while(t>0){
        int col = r.nextInt(m);
        boolean aggiunta = aggiungiPedina(griglia, col, primoGiocatore);
        while(!aggiunta){
            col = r.nextInt(m);
            aggiunta = aggiungiPedina(griglia, col, primoGiocatore);
        }
        col = r.nextInt(m);
        aggiunta = aggiungiPedina(griglia, col, secondoGiocatore);
        while(!aggiunta){
            col = r.nextInt(m);
            aggiunta = aggiungiPedina(griglia, col, secondoGiocatore);
        }
    }
    return griglia;
}

public boolean verificaVittoria(int[][] g, int p){
    for(int i=0;i<g.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<g[0].length;j++){
            if( g[i][j]==p ){
                boolean orizz = verificaOrizzontale(g,i,j,p);
                boolean vert = verificaVerticale(g,i,j,p);
                boolean obliquo = verificaObliquo(g,i,j,p);
                if( orizz||vert||obliquo){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean verificaOrizzontale(int[][]g,int row,int col,int p){
    int cont = 0;
    for(int j=col;j<g[0].length;j++){
        if( g[row][j]==p ){
            cont++;

        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;
    cont=0;
    for(int j=col;j>=0;j--){
        if( g[row][j]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean verificaVerticale(int[][]g,int row,int col,int p){
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=row;i<g.length;i++){
        if( g[i][col]==p ){
            cont++;

        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;
    cont=0;
    for(int i=row;i>=0;i--){
        if( g[i][col]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean verificaObliquo(int[][]g,int row,int col,int p){
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=row, j=col;i<g.length && j<g[0].length;i++, j++){
        if( g[i][j]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;

    cont=0;
    for(int i=row, j=col;i>=0 && j<g[0].length;i--, j++){
        if( g[i][j]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;

    for(int i=row, j=col;i>=0 && j>=0;i--, j--){
        if( g[i][j]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;

    for(int i=row, j=col;i<g.length && j>=0;i++, j--){
        if( g[i][j]==p ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cont==4)
        return true;
    return false;
}
}


package grafica;

import javax.swing.*;
import Forza4.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Forza4GUI
{   private JFrame frame;

/* INIZIO PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  

private JButton bottoneN;
private JLabel etichetta1;

private ArrayList<JButton> bottoniGriglia;
/* FINE PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  

public Forza4GUI()
{   frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    impostaLF();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    inizializzaContenuto();
    /* INIZIO PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */
    frame.setBounds(30, 30, 630,650);
    frame.setTitle("Forza 4");
    /* FINE PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  
}

private ImageIcon caricaIcona(String nomeFile)
{   return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(nomeFile));
}

private void impostaLF()
{   try
    {   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void inizializzaContenuto()
{   /* INIZIO PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  
    bottoneN = new JButton("Nuova Partita");                        
    frame.getContentPane().add(bottoneN);                   
    bottoneN.setBounds(150, 30, 120, 30);                       
    bottoneN.addActionListener(new PressioneBottoneN());

    etichetta1 = new JLabel("jj");
    frame.getContentPane().add(etichetta1);
    etichetta1.setBounds(350,30 , 100, 30);

    bottoniGriglia=new ArrayList<JButton>();
    ActionListener listener = new PressioneBottoni();
    int x=-90;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {   
        int y=-10;
        x+=90;
        for (int j=1;j<=6;j++)
        {
        k++;
        JButton bottone=new JButton();
        frame.getContentPane().add(bottone);
        bottone.addActionListener(listener);
        bottone.setActionCommand("" + k);
        y+=91;
        bottone.setBounds(x,y,90,91);
        bottoniGriglia.add(bottone);
        bottone.setIcon(caricaIcona("PallinoBiancoBordo.png"));
        }
    }

    /* FINE PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  
}

/* INIZIO PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  

private class PressioneBottoni implements ActionListener
{   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}

private class PressioneBottoneN implements ActionListener
{   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        etichetta1.setText("Ricomincia!");
    }
}
/* FINE PARTE DA PERSONALIZZARE */  

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Forza4 griglia = new Forza4();
    griglia.inizializzaGriglia(7,6,1);
    Forza4GUI GUI= new Forza4GUI(); //DA PERSONALIZZARE CON IL NOME DELLA CLASSE CREATA
}
}
```

Comment: we need the code of `Connect4` and `Connect4GUI` to help

Comment: I've done, i hope it is understandable

Comment: Firstly add all components to the Top Level Container, and then set it's visible property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a constructor for "Connect4GUI" that accepts a parameter of the class "Connect4":

```
public class Connect4GUI {
     private Connect4 myConnect4;

     public Connect4GUI (Connect4 c){
           myConnect4 = c;
     }

    //..............
}
```

Then your main becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     Connect4 grid = new Connect4();
     grid.inizializeGrid(7,6);
     Connect4GUI GUI= new Connect4GUI(grid);
}
```

Then you can access "myConnect4" in the methods of "Connect4GUI".

EDIT:

you have to call the default constructor from this new constructor:

```
public class Connect4GUI {
     private Connect4 myConnect4;

     public Connect4GUI (Connect4 c){
           this();
           myConnect4 = c;
     }

    //..............
}
```

Comment: I tried in this way but it starts the process without creating the window with the GUI

Comment: Excuse me but I don't get how it should work...I have only one constructor that requires a Connect4 instance in fact it gives me an error

Comment: The class "Forza4GUI" in your code (which corresponds to Connect4GUI) has a default constructor (a constructor without parameters). Now, it must have two constructors (default + the new one)

Comment: Yes,but it tells me that Forza4GUI(Forza 4) in Forza4GUI cannot be applied to ()